# What happens when you lose all references to a Python thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

Long story short... what happens when all references to a `threading.Thread` object are lost, such as in this function:

```
def myfunc():
    def thread_func():
        while True:
            do_useful_things()
    thethread = threading.Thread(target = thread_func)
    thethread.run()
    return
```

It kinda looks like the thread keeps going, but it is behaving oddly and I wondered if there might be odd things happening because the garbage collector improperly deleted it or something.

Or do threads continue normally even if the spawning thread isn't actively keeping track of them itself (I know `threading` itself has means of getting the active threads)?

Comment: If threading can get the active threads, then you didn't lost all reference to a python thread.

Comment: Running threads are usually (read: all GC:d languages I'm familiar with) considered GC roots (i.e. they are not garbage, and anything they reference -- directly and indirectly -- is also not garbage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert on threading but, from what I am aware, if you call `thethread.run` on it, it executes in the current thread (the main thread of execution thereby blocking execution) and then dies. In this case it will get garbage collected after the function ends as a local variable inside that function.

Instead, if you use `thethread.start()` it gets sent to a separate thread of its own where it executes. In this case, [there's a mapping](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/threading.py#l730) in the `threading` module that always keeps a reference to it:

```
_active = {}    # maps thread id to Thread object
```

so, in that case, there's always at least one reference to the thread you've created. This eventually gets removed after it performs its work.

Comment: That was in fact the mistake I made. Whoops. Good info anyway.